# PHP HTML, need help on how to pass on the data related to checkboxes on form submit

Tags: php, checkbox

Have a form with a table having 3 columns,populated dynamially.. Col1 and Col2 populated from Database, the col3 is populated with checkboxes, generated dynamically based on the number of rows returned from database for filling in Col1 and Col2.

### Meaning for each rown in a table have a checkbox in Column3.

I want to know how can I pass on the values from a Col1 and Col2 to next page based on the checkbox/es selected for the row/s??

If a checkboxes in Row1 and Row3 are checked , then want the details of col1 and col2 for Row1 and Row3 on next page.

Comment: please provide code so that we could see it instead of bashing our heads on something we dont see

Comment: <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="form2.php">
echo '<table>';

echo  '<tbody>';
    echo  '<tr>';
      echo '<td>Col1</td>';
      echo '<td>Col2</td>';
      echo '<td >Col3</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
  {
   echo "<tr><td>";
 echo $row["name"];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row["model"];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chkbxs[]" value="checked" />';
 echo "</td></tr>";
  }
}
echo  '</tbody>';
echo  '</table>>';
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Continue...">
</FORM>

Answer (score 3):

you can use javascript, better jquery library to assign that columns data to some hidden inputs before form submit, something like this

```
$("#formId").submit(function(e) {

    var col1 = $(".col1").html();
    var col2 = $(".col2").html();

     $("#hidCol1").val(col1);
     $("#hidCol2").val(col2);

     return true;
});



  <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="form2.php">
     <input id="hidCol1" type="hidden" name="col1">
     <input id="hidCol2" type="hidden" name="col2">
 <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr/>
      <td class="col1">Col1</td>
      <td class="col2">Col2</td>
      <td >Col3</td>
    </tr>
 <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php  echo $row["name"]; ?> </td>
       <td><?php $row["model"]; ?></td>
       <td> <input type="checkbox" name="chkbxs[]" value="checked" /></td>
   </tr>
  <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
 </table>

    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Continue...">
 </FORM>
```

when you submit your form your hidden inputs will contain `col1` and `col2` values. And I would suggest to not use `echo` for usual html tags, you can do them as usual tags

Comment: thank you, will consider this..and get back if I got this working at my end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FORM
use the columns Col1 and Col2 with `input=readyonly`
CSS and remove the edges of inputs

Try:

```
<style>
input.readonly{border: none; background: transparent;}
</style>

<td><input class="readonly" name="col1" value="content col1" readonly="readonly"></td>
<td><input class="readonly" name="col2" value="content col2" readonly="readonly"></td>
```

That way no need javascript
making your site more accessible

Or try with hidden (without the need for css):

```
<td><input name="col1" value="content col1" type="hidden">content col1</td>
<td><input name="col2" value="content col2" type="hidden">content col2</td>
```

Comment: thank you..will try this at my end and wil comment here if it works out